# Oracle - Check if row exists before deleting several rows in other tables

Tags: oracle, plsql, row, delete-row

I would like to delete several rows in an Oracle database if the ID of a main table already exists:
I tried to do first a SELECT to check if the ID exists in the main table before deleting the rows based on the ID in the other tables:

```
DECLARE
    PROJECT_ID PLS_INTEGER;
    PROJECT_ID_TO_DELETE PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
    PROJECT_ID := PROJECTS_SEQ.nextval; 
    SELECT PROJ_ID INTO PROJECT_ID_TO_DELETE FROM PROJECTS WHERE PROJ_NAME_EN LIKE 'FD Project - CSB - A.1 - CFT - Final Reject of an Increase Movement - Seb';    
    IF PROJECT_ID_TO_DELETE IS NULL THEN
        DELETE FROM PROJECTS_ORG WHERE PROJ_ID = PROJECT_ID_TO_DELETE;
        DELETE FROM PROJECTS WHERE PROJ_ID  = PROJECT_ID_TO_DELETE;
        DELETE FROM MVT_ONGOING WHERE MVT_ONGOING_PROJ_ID  = PROJECT_ID_TO_DELETE;
        DELETE FROM MVT_HISTORY WHERE MVT_HISTORY_PROJ_ID  = PROJECT_ID_TO_DELETE;
    END IF;
    Insert into PROJECTS (PROJ_ID, ...) values (PROJECT_ID, ...);
    Insert into PROJECTS_ORG (PROJ_ID, ...) values (PROJECT_ID, ...);
    Insert into MVT_ONGOING (MVT_ONGOING_PROJ_ID, ...);
    Insert into MVT_HISTORY (PROJ_ID, ...) values (PROJECT_ID, ...);
END;
```

I get an error "no data found"

Could you please help me with that in order to find the best optimized solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
DECLARE
   project_id_new        PLS_INTEGER;
   project_id_to_delete  PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
   BEGIN
      SELECT proj_id
        INTO project_id_to_delete
        FROM projects
       WHERE proj_name_en LIKE 'blabla';

      DELETE FROM projects_org WHERE proj_id = project_id_to_delete;
      DELETE FROM projects     WHERE proj_id = project_id_to_delete;
      DELETE FROM mvt_ongoing  WHERE mvt_ongoing_proj_id = project_id_to_delete;
      DELETE FROM mvt_history  WHERE mvt_history_proj_id = project_id_to_delete;
   EXCEPTION
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
      THEN
         NULL;
   END;

   project_id_new := seq.nextval;
   
   INSERT INTO projects (project_id)     VALUES (project_id_new);
   INSERT INTO projects_org (project_id) VALUES (project_id_new);
END;
```

What does it do?

- tries to find `PROJ_ID`
- if it finds it, performs `DELETE`s

  - you don't have to use `IF`; if it is found, it's known. If it isn't found, exception is raised
- otherwise, `NO_DATA_FOUND` exception is raised and **handled**

  - I chose to do *nothing*, you might want to do something else

As of inserting (as you commented, you'd want to do it always): enclose deleting section into its own `BEGIN-EXCEPTION-END` block so that possible `no_data_found` error is handled. Then, find `project_id_new` value (for example, using a sequence) and use it in `INSERT` statements.

Comment: Thanks. In fact when I tried with IF, I done after the IF command, several additional commands (INSERT). Now I don't know how to proceed, because the INSERT commands were also in the BEGIN. I need to the INSERT command everytime. Could You please tell me how to do because I don't know how to put the INSERT ?

Comment: I edit the topic above for the query that I want

Comment: INSERTs go below DELETE (see my edited code). Though, you have to get some value into PROJECT_ID, otherwise it'll be NULL. Saying that you have to perform INSERT "every time", does it mean that you'll INSERT regardless of whether SELECT returned anything or not?

Comment: I have tried, but it seems that the insert commands are not executed as the select the select return no result and as in the exception there is nothing. In fact the goal is to remove only if the item is already existing before to do the insert in order to avoid to have 2 entries with the same label

Comment: Please, re-read my whole answer (including code).

Comment: Many Thanks, Sorry perhaps I was not sufficient clear: myhe goal is to remove the rows only if the item is already existing before to do the insert in order to avoid to have 2 entries with the same label.